# How to load keras model onto Raspberry Pi

Tags: tensorflow, keras, raspberry-pi3, h5py

I cannot find how to use keras model that I've trained on my PC to load onto my Raspberry Pi 3.

How can I move it from the PC to the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow support Raspberry Pi officially since v1.9.

Just:

```sh
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Then you may upload your python code along with .h5 model to the device to run.

Comment: To upload model, do I just copy paste the model from my PC onto the SD card?